# What is the difference between DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager and AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-authorized-manager-provider), the only recommendation I found is

> The DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager is designed to be used within the context of a HttpServletRequest. When operating outside of a HttpServletRequest context, use AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager instead.

I could test that `WebClient` calls hang using the `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` outside the scope of a servlet request, however, nothing weird happens if I use `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` inside the context of a servlet request. Then, what's the difference between the two of them?

Answer (score 8):

The main difference as you noted from the docs is where they would be used. This may be less obvious from the outside looking in, but would be more obvious inside the framework. But perhaps an easier way to explain why they're different is to look at what they encapsulate.

- `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` uses a `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`

  - which has a method signature of `loadAuthorizedClient(String clientRegistrationId, Authentication principal, HttpServletRequest request)`
- `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` uses a `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`

  - which has a method signature of `loadAuthorizedClient(String clientRegistrationId, String principalName)`

So `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` is what I guess you'd call "request based" and `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` is "service based", which really just means everything else.

The API docs will be helpful here:

- [DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.html)
- [AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.html)

Update:

> What would be the added value to have the request as a parameter?

As an interface, declaring that the `loadAuthorizedClient` method accepts the request as a parameter means any future implementation can use the request to influence its decision. The default implementation (`DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`) does this, since the `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` utilizes the request to access the session.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Steve, but I'm still not sure I get the difference. What would be the added value to have the request as a parameter?

Comment: As an interface, declaring that the `loadAuthorizedClient` method accepts the request as a parameter means any future implementation can use the request to influence its decision. The default implementation does this, since the `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` utilizes the request to access the session.